# A way to evaluate $\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^{n+1}n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, divergent-series

The binomial expansion of $(a+b)^{-2}$ is given as

$$(a+b)^{-2}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^{n+1}na^{-1-n}b^{n-1}\tag{I think}$$

And when $a=b=1$,

$$2^{-2}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^{n+1}n=1-2+3-4+\dots$$

So I was wondering if this were a way to evaluate the divergent summation in a ramanujan sort of meaning.

Comment: you should study a complex analysis course

Comment: @user1952009 sadly, that is difficult without having first taken Calculus, and I'm a high school student, self taught everything I know on this site.  :/  More self teaching is difficult.

Comment: no, I know your level and I tell you you are capable. of course you'll need re-proving first some calculus theorems about integrals derivatives sequences series and trigonometric functions, but you can also prove those during studying a complex analysis course (and you'll have all your divergent series examples to help you).

Comment: @user1952009 Cool, thanks for the confidence boost, but darn, with my actually classes, the amount of time I get to digest new math material is shrinking.

Comment: @user1952009 I took your advice and learned some complex analysis :D

Comment: @reuns So I did some complex analysis. What else would you recommend?

Comment: Hi. I looked at your questions and answers I didn't find many Fourier analysis topics. See [thisone](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2404980/dirac-delta-and-exponential-integral/2404982#2404982) about proving the Fourier inversion theorem in a few lines. 1 year ago I didn't know anything about algebraic number fields and abstract algebra, and after reading questions MSE and wikipedia I could obtain a basic knowledge for studying this topic.

Comment: Cool, thanks :-) @reuns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is [Abel Summation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergent_series#Abel_summation) (Regularization) because it comes from defining:

$$f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nz^n$$
 and evaluating:

$$A:=\lim_{z\rightarrow 1^{-}}\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nz^{n}.$$

In your case:

$$f(z)=\frac{1}{(1+z)^2}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty ((-1)^nn)z^n.$$

You can find other ways to regularize your sum [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_%E2%88%92_2_%2B_3_%E2%88%92_4_%2B_%E2%8B%AF).

Comment: How have I changed since this post...