# Computation of the following integral

Tags: integration, improper-integrals

What is the most general way to compute (formally not numerically) the following integral:

$\int_\mathbb{R}\exp(iuz - \frac{(x-z)^2}{2t})dz, \space t>0$

Comment: What do you mean by "most general". Typically, just complete the square and use the gaussian integral.

Comment: So, the standard way is to use "gaussian integral" ? Could you write the solution ?

Comment: Oh, now I ser that there is also an $i$. Then One has to work a bit with paths, but essentially THE same gös through. I am afk, so someone else will probably help before I come back.

Comment: I recently did this in [an answer to another question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2404980/dirac-delta-and-exponential-integral/2406250#2406250). Also read the comments!